# Reshapint ndarray from 2d to 3d

Tags: python, numpy

I am currently having problems reshaping an numpy.ndarray from 2d to 3d..

the current shape of my numpy.ndarray is (221286, 2050) and i need it to be
 (221286 , 1, 2050)

I tried doing it like this:

```
train_set_data_vstacked_normalized_reshaped = np.reshape(train_set_data_vstacked_normalized.shape[0],1,train_set_data_vstacked_normalized.shape[1])
```

but this seem to create a way different numpy.ndarray....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.reshape`, when used as a function, takes the array to reshape as first argument, and the new shape as second. So this should do it:

```
shape = your_long_named_array.shape
your_long_named_array_reshaped = np.reshape(your_long_named_array,
                                            (shape[0], 1, shape[1]))
```

You could also use the `.reshape` method of ndarrays, which doesn't require you to explicitly wrap the shape in a tuple:

```
your_long_named_array_reshaped = your_long_named_array.reshape(shape[0], 1,
                                                               shape[1])
```

Although for this particular case, the most convenient is probably to index the array with `np.newaxis`:

```
your_long_named_array_reshaped = your_long_named_array[:, np.newaxis, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) function.

```
train_set_data_vstacked_normalized_reshaped = np.expand_dims(train_set_data_vstacked_normalized.shape,axis=1)
```

example:

```
In [16]: x = np.zeros((221286, 2050))

In [17]: x.shape
Out[17]: (221286, 2050)

In [18]: y = np.expand_dims(x, axis=1)

In [19]: y.shape
Out[19]: (221286, 1, 2050)
```